# Ordering in noncommutative multiply

Tags: pattern-matching, algebraic-manipulation

I have an expression like

```
s ** p1 ** p1 ** p2 - s ** p1 ** p2 ** p1
```

Which should be zero because the commutator between `p1` and `p2` is zero (this example is from quantum mechanics)

So I tried `ReplaceRepeated` on my expressions to order them, and a `Simplify` should then give `0`

For instance this rule works:

```
p2 ** p1 //. {a_ ** b_ /; ! OrderedQ[{a, b}] -> Com[a, b] + b ** a}
```

but this one never stops :

```
p2 ** p1 ** p1 //. {a_ ** b_ /; ! OrderedQ[{a, b}] -> Com[a, b] + b ** a}
```

Thus I tried

```
p2 ** p1 //. {a_ ** b_ /; Except[a neq b, ! OrderedQ[{a, b}]] -> Com[a, b] + b ** a}
```

but it doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 7):

The issue in your rule is that `a_` and `b_` don't necessarily need to be symbols. What if your `a` matches a larger portion of the expression?

```
OrderedQ[{(Com[p2, p1] + p1 ** p2), p1}]
(* False *)
```

Then the rule would be applied and I'm not sure this your intention. Please try this set of rules. I have added some print commands so that you see which rule was applied:

```
r = {
  a_Symbol ** b_Symbol /; ! OrderedQ[{a, b}] :> (Print["R1"]; 
    Com[a, b] + b ** a),
  (e1_ + e2_) ** e3_ :> (Print["R2"]; e1 ** e3 + e2 ** e3),
  e3_ ** (e1_ + e2_) :> (Print["R3"]; e3 ** e1 + e3 ** e2)
}

s ** p1 ** p1 ** p2 - s ** p1 ** p2 ** p1 //. r

(* -Com[s, p1] ** Com[p2, p1] - p1 ** s ** Com[p2, p1] *)
```

If `Com[p2,p1]` is zero, then the above expression vanishes.

---

You made a comment

> mathematica can't reduce mostly the same expression: `f[x1] ** p2 + g[x1] ** p1 ** p1 ** p2 - g[x1] ** p1 ** p2 ** p1 //. r`

Yes, that's because I only allowed the rule to apply if the `a_` and `b_` are symbols. `f[x1]` is not a symbol. It is an expression with the head `f`.

The big catch here is the following: An expression like `x+y` is basically of the same type as `f[x1]`. It is `Plus[x,y]` and now let's assume you have to following:

```
z ** (x + y)
```

As you can check easily, `OrderedQ[{z, (x + y)}]` is `False` and therefore, your rule would apply which would result in

```
z ** (x + y) /. a_ ** b_ :> Com[a, b] + b ** a
(* Com[z, x + y] + (x + y) ** z *)
```

I thought that this is not what you want. Therefore, I explicitly forced the `a` and `b` in the replacement rule to be symbols. But this will lead to exactly the situation you have found, where `f[x1]` is not simplified.

Comment: Thanks! this looks great. But can you explain me why: g[x1] ** p1 ** p1 ** p2 - g[x1] ** p1 ** p2 ** p1 //. r gives now zero as I wanted, but mathematica can't reduce mostly the same expression : f[x1] ** p2 + g[x1] ** p1 ** p1 ** p2 - g[x1] ** p1 ** p2 ** p1 //. r  Then he doesn't simplify the last term!

Comment: @Jip I tried to give some further explanation in the end of my answer. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 4):

Try [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC). You can do what you want with

```
<< NC`
<< NCAlgebra`
SetNonCommutative[p1, p2];
expr = s ** p1 ** p1 ** p2 - s ** p1 ** p2 ** p1
NCReplaceRepeated[expr, p2 ** p1 -> p1 ** p2]
```

which will evaluate to `0`. Single lower case letters, e.g. `s`, are noncommutative by default.